Geometry Optimizations for Excited States
I am studying computational photochemistry and I am confused about some steps. I would appreciate any help someone could offer.
I was asked to perform geometry optimization for excited states. However, before that, I conducted a TDDFT calculation. I'm analyzing the differences between the two calculations to confirm my understanding.
TDDFT operates according to the Franck–Condon principle, which means that the geometry does not change upon excitation. I calculate the vertical excitation energy needed to reach the excited electronic states in this approach. On the other hand, geometry optimization for excited states aim to determine the geometry at the minimum energy of this state (or to assess whether such a minimum exists at all).
For example, does in the image, the black dot represents the results of TDDFT, while the purple dot represents the results of Geometry Optimization for Excited State?.


TDDFT can be used both for determining excited state energies at a particular geometry as well as to optimize the structure on a particular excited state's potential energy surface (PES).
As you mentioned, TDDFT will give you the vertical excitation energy (or energies) at a particular geometry. But it can also give you the nuclear gradients along this excited state's PES. Using these gradients (and potentially even the excited excited state Hessian or higher order derivatives if you wanted), you can traverse the excited state PES to find a minimum energy geometry.
To do a TDDFT geometry optimization in Gaussian, you would need a route section with the keywords Opt TD Root=N NStates=M where N is the state you are interested in and M is the number of states to calculate. M >= N as you need enough states not just to reach the nth excited state, but also to ensure you have actually converged its excitation energy/coefficients.

Great! It's exactly what I was thinking. Dear Tyberius, could you help with one more thing? Do you know how to perform optimization for excited states in Gaussian?

https://joaquinbarroso.com/2021/01/26/geometry-optimizations-for-excited-states/

@TreinoToday update to include a bit about running a TDDFT geopt. The article linked by Tensor is also a very nice, short tutorial on this.
